# How to get specific data from JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a dict stored under the variable `parsed`:

```
{
    "8119300029": {
        "store": 4,
        "total": 4,
        "web": 4   
    },
    "8119300030": {
        "store": 2,
        "total": 2,
        "web": 2   
    },
    "8119300031": {
        "store": 0,
        "total": 0,
        "web": 0   
    },
    "8119300032": {
        "store": 1,
        "total": 1,
        "web": 1   
    },
    "8119300033": {
        "store": 0,
        "total": 0,
        "web": 0   
    },
    "8119300034": {
        "store": 2,
        "total": 2,
        "web": 2   
    },
    "8119300036": {
        "store": 0,
        "total": 0,
        "web": 0   
    },
    "8119300037": {
        "store": 0,
        "total": 0,
        "web": 0   
    },
    "8119300038": {
        "store": 2,
        "total": 2,
        "web": 2
    },
    "8119300039": {
        "store": 3,
        "total": 3,
        "web": 3
    },
    "8119300040": {
        "store": 3,
        "total": 3,
        "web": 3
    },
    "8119300041": {
        "store": 0,
        "total": 0,
        "web": 0
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the "web" value from each JSON entry but can only get the key values.

```
for x in parsed:
     print(x["web"])
```

I tried doing this ^ but kept getting this error: "string indices must be integers". Can somebody explain why this is wrong?

Comment: Post a minimum complete code that can be executed with your json

Comment: Have you converted it from Json to python object?

Answer (score 1):

A little information on your parsed data there: this is basically a dictionary of dictionaries. I won't go into too much of the nitty gritty but it would do well to read up a bit on `json`: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

In your example, `for x in parsed` is iterating through the keys of the `parsed` dictionary, e.g. `8119300029`, `8119300030`, etc. So `x` is a key (in this case, a string), not a dictionary. The reason you're getting an error about not indexing with an integer is because you're trying to index a string -- for example `x[0]` would give you the first character `8` of the key `8119300029`.

If you need to get each `web` value, then you need to access that key in the `parsed[x]` dictionary:

```
for x in parsed:
    print(parsed[x]["web"])
```

Output:

```
4
2
0
...
```

Answer (score 1):

because your x variable is dict key name

```
for x in parsed:
    print(parsed[x]['web'])
```